# Removing co-authors from a new version of the paper

Tags: publications, etiquette, authorship

I work in an industry research lab. Some time ago, my team wrote a paper. Despite the core authors of the paper being 2 team members (author A and B), we decided to be inclusive and add 2 additional team members as authors (author C and D), even if their contribution was very limited (basically they took a read and provided feedback on language and grammar).

At that time, the paper got rejected. Now, we wrote a new version of the paper. Some parts are significantly different, others are as before. Also, the two additional co-authors C and D, whose contribution was limited, left the company.

My question: is it fair not to include authors C and D in the new version of the paper?

Comment: Look up authorship code --  In Australia, we use https://www.nhmrc.gov.au/about-us/publications/australian-code-responsible-conduct-research-2018

Answer (score 6):

> basically they took a read and provided feedback on language and
> grammar

If that is really all they did, they shouldn't have been listed as coauthors. Thus, it is entirely appropriate to remove them now. However, you should thank them in the Acknowledgements section.

I can't comment on "fairness".

Answer (score 0):

As described, you were wrong to give them honorary authorships in the first place. They should not be retained.